# How to set interesting integrals

Tags: integration, education

I'm teaching integration by substitution and integration by parts and I'd like to make some interesting problems. I'd like to be able to use the chain rule and the product rule to reverse engineer some nice problems.

I would really like a non-obvious substitution to lead to an integral that needs to be integrated by parts, or an integral by parts that leads to an integral needing a substitution.

Like I said: I would like a method to reverse engineer. Any ideas?

**Edit:** I could, of course, pick a complicated function and differentiate it. But that would give an even more complicated integrand. I want a nice problem. A nice, compact integrand that - via a cunning substitution - becomes do-able. An Example would be:
$$\int \cos 2x \cdot \ln\left(\cos x \right) \cdot \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: "reverse engineering an integral" = "writing down a complicated function and then taking its derivative"

Comment: @BaronVT Which will often be a more complicated function, and not a nice compact integrand.

Comment: I can't think of any examples off the top of my head, but if there is a function defined in terms of elementary functions, and yet it is only finitely differentiable (say less than 5 times), that would be a decent candidate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that:
$$
\int f(g(x))g'(x)dx = \int f(t)dt 
$$
with $t=g(x)$

e.g.
$$
f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2+a^2} \qquad g(x) = e^{x^2+b} 
$$
gives:
$$
g'(x)= 2xe^{x^2+b}
$$

and a integral of the form:

$$
\int \dfrac{2xe^{x^2+b}}{e^{2(x^2+b)}+a^2}dx
$$
can be integrated with the substitution 
$$
t=e^{x^2+b}
$$

If you want to hide better the substitution you can write:

$$
\int \dfrac{2exe^x}{e^{2(x^2+1)}+\pi^2} dx
$$

Answer (score -4):

You can try taking some complicated derivatives and integrating them to obtain their integral counterparts. For example, try this:

```
  $ y= \{arctan {In{x^3} + {x^6}sin{4x} + {e^{4x}}\$
```

Differentiate and then set it up as an integral. That should keep both you and your students busy for awhile..........lol

Comment: Sigh.My fan club at work. Someone please edit the code on my reply.